# AWS OpsWorks - Cannot deploy my application with AWS OpsWorks, especially cannot succeed in migration

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-opsworks

Following this document(http://railsconf2015-aws.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/), I'm trying to deploy my rails application with AWS OpsWorks. However, I failed to do, especially when I tried to migrate it.

This is error log.

```
Your bundle is complete!
Gems in the groups test and development were not installed.
It was installed into /home/deploy/.bundler/sample_app

[2015-07-26T08:21:32+00:00] INFO: No database adapter specified for sample_app, guessing
[2015-07-26T08:21:32+00:00] INFO: Looks like sample_app uses mysql2 in its Gemfile
[2015-07-26T08:21:32+00:00] INFO: Processing template[/srv/www/sample_app/shared/config/database.yml] action create (/var/lib/aws/opsworks/cache.stage2/cookbooks/deploy/definitions/opsworks_deploy.rb line 115)
[2015-07-26T08:21:32+00:00] INFO: deploy[/srv/www/sample_app] queueing checkdeploy hook /srv/www/sample_app/releases/20150726082129/deploy/before_migrate.rb
[2015-07-26T08:21:32+00:00] INFO: Processing template[/srv/www/sample_app/shared/config/database.yml] action create (/var/lib/aws/opsworks/cache.stage2/cookbooks/deploy/definitions/opsworks_deploy.rb line 115)
[2015-07-26T08:21:32+00:00] INFO: deploy[/srv/www/sample_app] made pre-migration symlinks
[2015-07-26T08:21:32+00:00] INFO: deploy[/srv/www/sample_app] set user to deploy
[2015-07-26T08:21:32+00:00] INFO: deploy[/srv/www/sample_app] set group to nginx
[2015-07-26T08:21:32+00:00] INFO: deploy[/srv/www/sample_app] migrating deploy

================================================================================
Error executing action `deploy` on resource 'deploy[/srv/www/sample_app]'
================================================================================


Chef::Exceptions::Exec
----------------------
if [ -f Gemfile ]; then echo 'OpsWorks: Gemfile found - running migration with bundle exec' && /usr/local/bin/bundle exec /usr/local/bin/rake db:migrate; else echo 'OpsWorks: no Gemfile - running plain migrations' && /usr/local/bin/rake db:migrate; fi returned 1, expected 0


Cookbook Trace:
---------------
/var/lib/aws/opsworks/cache.stage2/cookbooks/opsworks_commons/libraries/monkey_patch_deploy_provider.rb:45:in `block in migrate'
/var/lib/aws/opsworks/cache.stage2/cookbooks/opsworks_commons/libraries/monkey_patch_deploy_provider.rb:39:in `migrate'


Resource Declaration:
---------------------
# In /var/lib/aws/opsworks/cache.stage2/cookbooks/deploy/definitions/opsworks_deploy.rb

65:     deploy deploy[:deploy_to] do
66:       provider Chef::Provider::Deploy.const_get(deploy[:chef_provider])
67:       keep_releases deploy[:keep_releases]
68:       repository deploy[:scm][:repository]
69:       user deploy[:user]
70:       group deploy[:group]
71:       revision deploy[:scm][:revision]
72:       migrate deploy[:migrate]
73:       migration_command deploy[:migrate_command]
74:       environment deploy[:environment].to_hash
75:       purge_before_symlink(deploy[:purge_before_symlink]) unless deploy[:purge_before_symlink].nil?
76:       create_dirs_before_symlink(deploy[:create_dirs_before_symlink])
77:       symlink_before_migrate(deploy[:symlink_before_migrate])
78:       symlinks(deploy[:symlinks]) unless deploy[:symlinks].nil?
79:       action deploy[:action]
80: 
81:       if deploy[:application_type] == 'rails' && node[:opsworks][:instance][:layers].include?('rails-app')
82:         restart_command "sleep #{deploy[:sleep_before_restart]} && #{node[:opsworks][:rails_stack][:restart_command]}"
83:       end
84: 



Compiled Resource:
------------------
# Declared in /var/lib/aws/opsworks/cache.stage2/cookbooks/deploy/definitions/opsworks_deploy.rb:65:in `block in from_file'

deploy("/srv/www/sample_app") do
params {:deploy_data=>{"deploy_to"=>"/srv/www/sample_app", "chef_provider"=>"Timestamped", "keep_releases"=>5, "current_path"=>"/srv/www/sample_app/current", "document_root"=>"public", "ignore_bundler_groups"=>["test", "development"], "absolute_document_root"=>"/srv/www/sample_app/current/public/", "rake"=>"/usr/local/bin/rake", "migrate"=>true, "migrate_command"=>"if [ -f Gemfile ]; then echo 'OpsWorks: Gemfile found - running migration with bundle exec' && /usr/local/bin/bundle exec /usr/local/bin/rake db:migrate; else echo 'OpsWorks: no Gemfile - running plain migrations' && /usr/local/bin/rake db:migrate; fi", "rails_env"=>"production", "action"=>"deploy", "user"=>"deploy", "group"=>"nginx", "shell"=>"/bin/bash", "home"=>"/home/deploy", "sleep_before_restart"=>0, "stack"=>{"needs_reload"=>true}, "enable_submodules"=>true, "shallow_clone"=>false, "delete_cached_copy"=>true, "purge_before_symlink"=>["log", "tmp/pids", "public/system"], "create_dirs_before_symlink"=>["tmp", "public", "config"], "symlink_before_migrate"=>{"config/database.yml"=>"config/database.yml", "config/memcached.yml"=>"config/memcached.yml"}, "symlinks"=>{"system"=>"public/system", "pids"=>"tmp/pids", "log"=>"log"}, "environment"=>{"RAILS_ENV"=>"production", "RUBYOPT"=>"", "RACK_ENV"=>"production", "HOME"=>"/home/deploy", "SECRET_KEY_BASE"=>"42426faeafcbeafc1ac73a23d0844b7e3f4a27d8cc5a15b8c9ea9e092bab7f0d2f87c5102411aac919a3425bbe4560fb686e22525871236b9322c4b5573bf4da"}, "environment_variables"=>{"SECRET_KEY_BASE"=>"42426faeafcbeafc1ac73a23d0844b7e3f4a27d8cc5a15b8c9ea9e092bab7f0d2f87c5102411aac919a3425bbe4560fb686e22525871236b9322c4b5573bf4da"}, "ssl_support"=>false, "auto_npm_install_on_deploy"=>true, "nodejs"=>{"restart_command"=>"monit restart node_web_app_sample_app", "stop_command"=>"monit stop node_web_app_sample_app", "port"=>80}, "application"=>"sample_app", "application_type"=>"rails", "auto_bundle_on_deploy"=>true, "deploying_user"=>"arn:aws:iam::934616152548:root", "domains"=>["sample_app"], "mounted_at"=>nil, "restart_command"=>nil, "ssl_certificate"=>nil, "ssl_certificate_key"=>nil, "ssl_certificate_ca"=>nil, "scm"=>{"scm_type"=>"git", "repository"=>"https://github.com/takuwan0405/sample_app.git", "revision"=>nil, "ssh_key"=>nil, "user"=>nil, "password"=>nil}, "database"=>{"host"=>"172.31.10.7", "database"=>"sample_app", "port"=>3306, "username"=>"root", "password"=>"k7gs5opqfr", "reconnect"=>true, "data_source_provider"=>"stack", "type"=>"mysql"}, "memcached"=>{"host"=>nil, "port"=>11211}}, :app=>"sample_app", :name=>nil}
provider Chef::Provider::Deploy::Timestamped
action [:deploy]
updated true
updated_by_last_action true
retries 0
retry_delay 2
deploy_to "/srv/www/sample_app"
environment {"RAILS_ENV"=>"production", "RUBYOPT"=>"", "RACK_ENV"=>"production", "HOME"=>"/home/deploy", "SECRET_KEY_BASE"=>"42426faeafcbeafc1ac73a23d0844b7e3f4a27d8cc5a15b8c9ea9e092bab7f0d2f87c5102411aac919a3425bbe4560fb686e22525871236b9322c4b5573bf4da", "LC_ALL"=>"C"}
repository_cache "cached-copy"
purge_before_symlink ["log", "tmp/pids", "public/system"]
create_dirs_before_symlink ["tmp", "public", "config"]
symlink_before_migrate {"config/database.yml"=>"config/database.yml", "config/memcached.yml"=>"config/memcached.yml"}
symlinks {"system"=>"public/system", "pids"=>"tmp/pids", "log"=>"log"}
revision "HEAD"
migrate true
remote "origin"
enable_submodules true
scm_provider Chef::Provider::Git
keep_releases 5
enable_checkout true
checkout_branch "deploy"
cookbook_name "deploy"
recipe_name "rails"
repo "https://github.com/takuwan0405/sample_app.git"
user "deploy"
group "nginx"
migration_command "if [ -f Gemfile ]; then echo 'OpsWorks: Gemfile found - running migration with bundle exec' && /usr/local/bin/bundle exec /usr/local/bin/rake db:migrate; else echo 'OpsWorks: no Gemfile - running plain migrations' && /usr/local/bin/rake db:migrate; fi"
restart_command "sleep 0 && ../../shared/scripts/unicorn clean-restart"
before_migrate #<Proc:0x007f2d074dcbb0@/var/lib/aws/opsworks/cache.stage2/cookbooks/deploy/definitions/opsworks_deploy.rb:100>
shared_path "/srv/www/sample_app/shared"
destination "/srv/www/sample_app/shared/cached-copy"
current_path "/srv/www/sample_app/current"
end



[2015-07-26T08:21:33+00:00] INFO: Running queued delayed notifications before re-raising exception
[2015-07-26T08:21:33+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
[2015-07-26T08:21:33+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
[2015-07-26T08:21:33+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/lib/aws/opsworks/cache.stage2/chef-stacktrace.out
[2015-07-26T08:21:33+00:00] ERROR: deploy[/srv/www/sample_app] (deploy::rails line 65) had an error: Chef::Exceptions::Exec: if [ -f Gemfile ]; then echo 'OpsWorks: Gemfile found - running migration with bundle exec' && /usr/local/bin/bundle exec /usr/local/bin/rake db:migrate; else echo 'OpsWorks: no Gemfile - running plain migrations' && /usr/local/bin/rake db:migrate; fi returned 1, expected 0
[2015-07-26T08:21:33+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
```

It seems that it succeeded in "bundle install".

With ssh, I went to /srv/www/sample_app/releases/20150726082129 and typed

```
rake db:migrate
```

then error sentences appeared like this.

```
Could not find i18n-0.7.0 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

Next, following this error sentences, I typed

```
sudo bundle install
```

then it says

```
Your bundle is complete!
Gems in the groups test and development were not installed.
It was installed into /home/deploy/.bundler/sample_app
```

however, it appears that gem is empty. If I typed

```
gem list
```

I cannot find gems specified in Gemfile

```
bigdecimal (1.2.6)
bundler (1.5.3)
io-console (0.4.3)
json (1.8.1)
kgio (2.9.3)
minitest (5.4.3)
power_assert (0.2.2)
psych (2.0.8)
rack (1.6.4)
raindrops (0.15.0)
rake (10.4.2)
rdoc (4.2.0)
test-unit (3.0.8)
unicorn (4.7.0)
```

I think these are hints to solve my problem.

I'm sorry that I'm not good at English so much, so if you cannot understand what I wanted you to help, please tell me unknown point.

Answer (score 0):

Opworks is a pain to debug via their logs. here are some tips to debug.

You cannot do it in the normal ec2-user account you may be using to ssh. Do this command to be the deploy user ...

```
sudo su - deploy
```

which will then allow you to go to your app at the ***current*** location ...

```
cd /srv/www/sample_app/current
```

you will now also be able to see logs, run rake, and such. In particular, now you can run your failed command ...

```
if [ -f Gemfile ]; then echo 'OpsWorks: Gemfile found - running migration with bundle exec' && /usr/local/bin/bundle exec /usr/local/bin/rake db:migrate; else echo 'OpsWorks: no Gemfile - running plain migrations' && /usr/local/bin/rake db:migrate; fi
```

One place to look is in the ***shared*** area configuration, logs, i.e. ...

```
/srv/www/sample_app/shared/config/unicorn.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used OpsWorks to deploy rails apps a lot and this kind of deployment error is usual.

If you somehow run into migration errors from deploying Ruby on Rails app in OpsWorks, just **SSH** to the server and go to you **last deployment folder** (e.g. for your case:  /srv/www/sample_app/releases/20150726082129).

Please be careful that "/srv/www/{your app name}/current" will only point to your last successful deployment from OpsWorks, if you have failed the deployment, better directly access the latest deployment folder under "/srv/www/{your app name}/releases/{deployment time}"

Instead of

```
rake db:migrate
```

You should **run**

```
sudo bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

You will then see more meaningful migration errors and you should know how to do then.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I succeeded in deploying my app. I should have done "rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production" in the last deployment folder through ssh!

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, at least it worked for me.

The reason why the migration fail can depend for many reason and the OpsWorks logs can't help us.
So as many of you suggested, **to understand exactly what is going on, we have to login via SSH to one of our instance and try to run the command that cause the failure.**

Login via ssh and then:

`su - deploy
$ cd /srv/www/mynextapp/releases/20150401052640
$ /usr/local/bin/bundle exec /usr/local/bin/rake db:migrate`

Now this command should fail, showing us why.

@n1t1nv3rma got this error:

`ExecJS::RuntimeUnavailable: Could not find a JavaScript runtime`

And he fixed it [in this way.](https://github.com/aws/opsworks-cookbooks/issues/258#issuecomment-88377353)

For me the error was:

`/usr/lib/postgresql/9.5/bin/pg_dump: invalid option -- 'i'
Try "pg_dump --help" for more information.
rake aborted!
Error dumping database`

**And I fixed it just updating to Rails 4.2.6** (before was 4.2.3 - There's a commit that removes the --i option).

Look here for more details: https://github.com/aws/opsworks-cookbooks/issues/258

Hope it helps.